# How was the wood grain aligned in this set of decorative wall panels?

Tags: wood, walls, staining, plywood, vinyl

[image]

Can anyone tell me how the wood finish look on this wall was achieved? My guess was either by staining plywood or using vinyl sticker.

I am planning to  build a wall panel similar to this and was trying to find an affordable option.

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are match grain veneer panels. They are usually made by attaching selected hardwood veneers to plywood using contact glues. Veneers can be purchased from specialty woodworking dealers.

The technique is not hard but requires some care (and practice) to get straight, bubble-free surfaces.

Comment: Plywood panels already veneered with hardwood (typically over a hardwood core such as Baltic birch)  can be purchased off-the-shelf, if you find the right supplies. Look for hardwood plywood.

Comment: @keshlam Very true. But that matched grain ... Often worth the trouble of a DIY woodworking project. But for beginners, your way is a great approach.

Comment: Granted, @bib. As always, trade-off between what's easier and what's prettier...

Comment: And those particular ones look to be book-matched both from the center sideways and from the center up and down - which says it almost has to be veneer, or the appearance would vary too much by the time the sandwich (or book) was opened out to the edges.

Answer (score 2):

It's book-matched panels. I can't tell from the photo whether it's veneer, plywood, or hardwood. Looks like kinda like european walnut, not pine/plywood... but without a closer look at the edges, I really couldn't say.

As far as affordable options...